# Drupal Webform module: e-mail only

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal Webform 6.x-2.9 - is there a way (some code snippet or module) to make the form 'e-mail only' and NOT store the submissions in the database? I googled for a solution and there was an idea to automatically clear the results from the database upon submission, but I'm not sure how to write such code. I'd prefer not to hack the module files and use Additional Processing option is possible. Any suggestions/code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a backup intended for if you have email issues or didn't receive it, there is a copy.

You could write a simple module with a cron hook that clears the submissions every hour.